# Pyvista model turns black after setting show_edges to True

Tags: pyvista

When I set the show_edges attribute of plotter to True, the whole model becomes black instead of the edges. I use wsl and ubuntu.
For example, I want to show a sphere with edges and this is what I get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsAKf.png

Codes:

```py
import pyvista as pv

sphere = pv.Sphere()

pl = pv.Plotter()
pl.add_mesh(sphere, show_edges=True)

pl.show()
```

Comment: Unfortunately we need a lot more information than that to help you. Do you have a small example that reproduces your issue? Does it also happen to a simple mesh such as `pv.Sphere()`? It's possible your mesh has so many edges that it looks black. But it could also be a rendering issue. We can only help debug code we can see. Please [edit] your question and include a [mcve].

Comment: I've editted the question. The issue is that even for a simple mesh, the mesh becomes black after show_edges are set to True.

Comment: OK, that's much better, thanks. Are you running this from a terminal, or perhaps part of a jupyter notebook, some IDE or similar? And could you please post the output of `pv.Report()`?